# Run mysqltuner.pl against azure database for MySQL service

Tags: mysql, database, azure, database-tuning, mysqltuner

I would like to run mysqltuner from my pc on a remote host.
The remote host is a MySQL database hosted on Azure (Azure Database service for MySQL). I dont have access to the virtual machine - just have credentials to connect to the database.

```
perl mysqltuner.pl --host xxxxxxx.mysql.database.azure.com --port 3306 --user myuser --pass 'password'
```

I get this error:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.13 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[!!] Couldn't find mysqladmin in your $PATH. Is MySQL installed?
```

How can I run the mysqltuner for azure databases?

Thank you!

Comment: checkout this answer by @rolandomysqldba:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/95288/52300

Comment: Checked this already, but didnt helped.

Comment: This works for me!
`perl mysqltuner.pl --host xxxxxxx.mysql.database.azure.com --port 3306 --socket /tmp/mysql.sock --user myuser@xxxxxx --pass 'mypassword' --forcemem 5000`

Comment: @sokolata Please post your complete mysqltuner.pl TEXT report and someone will be able to offer suggestions for improving your response time.